# Tkinter ingresar archivo externo

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

tengo que hacer para un trabajo de clase una interfaz que le ingrese una texto externo mediante un botón y buscar el archivo .txt en el ordenador y que lo que el archivo tenga de texto me lo transcriba a un cuadro de texto pero no se bien como hacerlo y no he encontrado nada concreto por internet, perdón si formulo mal la situación este es el codigo que tengo de momento:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from io import open
#Creación de la ventana Principal
ventanaPrincipal= Tk()
ventanaPrincipal.title("Tokenización")
ventanaPrincipal.config(bg="white")
ventanaPrincipal.geometry("1100x600")
ventanaPrincipal.resizable(0,0)

#Asignación de Labels
documentoLabel=Label(ventanaPrincipal,text="Documento: ",fg="red")
documentoLabel.grid(row=1,column=0)

htmlLabel=Label(ventanaPrincipal,text="Generar HTML")
htmlLabel.place(x=900,y=50)
htmlLabel.config(bg="#919696")

estructuraLabel=Label(ventanaPrincipal,text="Estructura de listas")
estructuraLabel.place(x=400,y=0)


#Configuraciones 
inputTexto= Text(ventanaPrincipal, width=30, height=25)
inputTexto.grid(row=2,column=1)

scrollVert=Scrollbar(ventanaPrincipal, command=inputTexto.yview)
scrollVert.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky="nsew")

inputTexto.config(yscrollcommand=scrollVert.set, bg="#6CF0F6")



#Asignación de Botones
botonArchivo=Button(ventanaPrincipal,text="Buscar Archivos", command=lambda: buscarArchivo())
botonArchivo.place(x=175,y=475)
botonArchivo.config(fg="blue",bg="yellow",font=("Times New Roman", 10))

botonLimpiar=Button(ventanaPrincipal,text="Limpiar")
botonLimpiar.place(x=70,y=475)

botonTokenizar=Button(ventanaPrincipal,text="Tokenizar")
botonTokenizar.place(x=400,y=475)

botonTraducir=Button(ventanaPrincipal,text="Traducir")
botonTraducir.place(x=500, y=475)

botonCrearHtml=Button(ventanaPrincipal,text="Crear archivo HTML")
botonCrearHtml.place(x=900,y=82)

botonTexto=Button(ventanaPrincipal,text="pruebaTexto",command=lambda:pruebaTexto())
botonTexto.place(x=900,y= 475)

#Funciones
def buscarArchivo():
    extension= ["*.txt"]
    archivo_abierto=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                title="Seleccione archivo",filetypes=(("txt files","*.txt"),
                ("all files","*.*")))
    print(archivo_abierto)



def pruebaTexto():
    archivo_texto=open("archivo.txt","r")
    
    texto=archivo_texto.read()
    

    archivo_texto.close()
    print(texto)


ventanaPrincipal.mainloop()
```

he asignado variso botones que les dare otro uso despues pero de momento donde tengo problemas es con lo de pasar el archivo .txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas usar un objeto de `Text()`?  Creo que puedes usar:

```
resultStringVar = StringVar()
inputTexto = Label(textvariable=resultStringVar)
inputTexto.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

y pasar el texto al `inputTexto` con:

```
def pruebaTexto():
    archivo_texto=open("archivo.txt","r")
    texto=archivo_texto.read()
    archivo_texto.close()
    resultStringVar.set(texto)
```